# How to update Bios for GigaBye ga-p35-s3 board?

Tags: bios

I downloaded the F7 bios from their website ([link](http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Support/Motherboard/BIOS_Model.aspx?ProductID=2546#anchor_os)).

Now what? It seems as if I need to prepare some kind of a dos bootable device because there is an autoexec.bat file in the extracted files. I could not find instructions.

Can anyone guide me. I don't want to trash the board by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format a bootable floppy or a bootable CD or a bootable USB key, and copy the autoexec.bat and other files to the root directory there. Then boot off that medium.

Windows can format the floppy for you. Nero can make a bootable CD-R for you. There are [various utilities](http://www.bootdisk.com/pendrive.htm) around the Internet to do the USB key.

Comment: OK. So this has to be done via an independent bootable device and not under Windows?

Comment: There should have been detailed instructions either included with the BIOS you downloaded, or on the site you downloaded the BIOS from.  I've never seen any board manufacturer that didn't do one or the other.  But yes, if it included an AUTOEXEC.BAT file, most likely you cannot do it through Windows.  You must create a boot disk.

Comment: Most experienced users do not trust Windows-based BIOS flash utilities. BIOS flashing is timing dependent and an unusually busy Windows system could scuttle an attempted flash, with bad consequences.